# $development_db_name$ does not exist error even after running db:create and db:migrate and getting report that they exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

So I seemingly successfully installed postgres for production for heroku deployment, but locally rails seems to not find/nor create the database.

When I go to localhost:3000 I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
FATAL: database "dimension_development" does not exist Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
```

When I run `$bin/rake db:create` I get:

```
~ already exists
```

Then, run db:migrate and restart the rails server, reload the page, and get same error.

So I tried instead to run `$bin/rake db:create:all` and got:

```
~ already exists
dimension_test already exists
dimension_production already exists
```

Then did `db:migrate` again but nothing changed.

If they already exist, why isn't rails finding them? I notice that in the `config/db` folder there is still the old `development.sqlite3` file but no postgres file.

Any idea what could be going on to cause this error?

My `database.yml` is:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: dimension_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: dimension_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: dimension_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Thanks! This has got me stumped and I haven't been able to find anything on stackoverflow dealing with this pitfall.

Comment: In case of postgresql you will not find any file like `development.sqlite3`. It's in case of sqlite only.

You did not provided database credential in your `database.yml` file might causing this error.
Try pass username and password as well.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much Dipak, makes my life much easier :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of postgresql you will not find any file like development.sqlite3. It's in case of sqlite only.

You did not provided database credential in your database.yml file might causing this error. Try pass username and password as well.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: dimension_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx
```